# Does for all k, n^k is O(2^n)?

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

Is it true that for all k, n^k is O(2^n)?

What I actually want to know whether this upper bound is correct. Like we can say n^2 is O(n^3) since it's true that n^2 < c * n^3, where c is a constant. SO similarly can I say that n^k < c * 2^n, for all value of k?

Comment: Are you asking if *calculating* n^k is an O(2^n) time complexity?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math question.

Comment: @paxdiablo, yes, whether calculating n^k takes less than O(2^n) time for any value of k?

Comment: @RaymondChen, so you think it's not algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity question!!!!

Comment: It is not a programming question, which is what this site is for.

Comment: Russel, then it depends on how you define an operation. If multiplication is O(1) the exponentiation is at most O(n) [since `x^7` can be done as `x*x*x*x*x*x*x`]. I think you're going to need to add some detail to the question (if it survives).

Comment: The answer is no. Many powers can be calculated in *O(1)* shifts, or in *O(log N)* multiplication steps.

Comment: @paxdiablo , I added some details about the question. Please help me if possible. Thanks.

Comment: for any k, there exists a corresponding constant c such that c * 2 ^ n is larger. you should find a algorithm book and read it first. O is actually a fairly weak bound

Comment: to directly answer your question, O(1) == O(log n) == O(n) == O(2 ^ n) so yes, you are right. but it doesn't make sense to relax O notation to your extent.

Comment: Read the defiition of O(f(n)) again. Does it say "for all n" at any point? Maybe "for all n that satisfy some condition"? What is that condition?

Comment: No, it doesn't say anything about n, only says for any value of k.

Comment: There's no k in O(f(n)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that there is always a constant `c` for any constant `k` such that `n^k < c * 2^n`, consider this: `(n+1)^k / n^k = ((n+1)/n)^k`. As `n` increases, `(n+1)/n` tends to `1`, thus `((n+1)/n)^k` tends to 1. This implies that the relative increase between values decreases as `n` increases.

Now consider `2^(n+1) / 2^n`. This is clearly `2`. Thus the relative increase stays the same as `n` increases. Thus there will be a `c` for every `k` such that `n^k < c * 2^n`

Comment: Thanks @Benson Lin, now it's bit clear .

Comment: not even remotely a proof of the concept